# JTable with 2 different data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Im using a JTable , loading on it a different data depending on the button pressed.

The problem is : when one of the data is loaded, if i try to load the other one, and pass ther mouse over the header or a cell, it updates the header/cell with the data from the first input, if there is data on the header/cell selected.

Any ideas on how to solve it? That's the code im using.

```
private static void setCompromissosTable(Object[][] data, Object[] header){
    try{
        compromissosTable.removeAll();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    compromissosTable = new JTable(data, header);
    compromissosTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);


    // Make the entire row selectable, but not editable
    int columnMax = compromissosTable.getColumnCount();
    for(int column = 0; column < columnMax; column++){
        Class<?> col_class = compromissosTable.getColumnClass(column);
        compromissosTable.setDefaultEditor(col_class, null);
    }

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(compromissosTable);
    pane.add(scrollPane);

    scrollPane.setBounds(btnAddCompromisso.getX(), 
            btnAddCompromisso.getHeight() + btnAddCompromisso.getY()  + 5
            , frame1.getWidth() - 20
            , frame1.getHeight() - 20);

    compromissosTable.revalidate();
    compromissosTable.repaint();

    compromissosTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {}
     //Change mouse behavior.
    );


}
```

Comment: My first thought is don't create or modify the `JTable` itself, but simply switch out the models

Comment: You "seem" to be using `null` layouts, which probably mean, based on your example, you are simply "overlapping" the new table ontop of the old one, which is why you are probably getting painting glitches.  Instead, avoid `null` layouts, don't create a new `JTable` each time, but simply update an existing `JTable` with a new model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is suspicious...

```
compromissosTable = new JTable(data, header);
//...
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(compromissosTable);
pane.add(scrollPane);
```

Basically, assuming that each time you want to switch data sets, you are calling this method, you are creating a new `JTable` and `JScrollPane` each time and then are adding it onto the UI...

What about the previous `JTable`?

Next is this...

```
scrollPane.setBounds(btnAddCompromisso.getX(), 
        btnAddCompromisso.getHeight() + btnAddCompromisso.getY()  + 5
        , frame1.getWidth() - 20
        , frame1.getHeight() - 20);
```

This looks like you're using a `null` layout.  Basically what it "looks" like is happening, is you're just stacking the `JScrollPane`s ontop of each other, which would explain, in part, the graphics glitches, as the components are actually been added at the same z-deepthness (essentially) and are competing with each other then they are updated.

Two simple answers...

1. Don't use `null` layouts.  Sure they "seem" like a good idea, but they have a tendency to turn around and bite you in strange and wonderful ways which are hard to diagnose and fix.  Use the layout management API which Swing was designed around
2. Update the `JTable`s model instead of creating a new `JTable`/`JScrollPane` each time

See [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Searched for ways to set new header/data into my JTable but could not find a way to replace it (just remove or add it). 
But anyway the problem was adding a new scrollPanel onto the UI everytime data changed, and the old one was still receiving my MouseEvent. Simply removing the scrollPanel everytime before adding it again solved my problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `JTable#setModel` will cause the entire table to be reloaded and the column headers to be removed automatically